# svelte returning invalid array length

Tags: svelte

I have an api that retrieves a collection from mongodb successfully. The console.log(posts) shows the expected array of post.

Iterating over the array with for {each} returns an error

> Home.svelte:90 Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Invalid array length

What have I missed? Why is a card for each post not returned?

Thanks for any help.

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  const apiBaseUrl = "http://localhost:5100/api";

  onMount(async () => {
    const res = await fetch(apiBaseUrl + "/list");
    posts = await res.json();
    console.log(posts)
  });

</script>

<div class="row">
    {#each posts as post}
      <div class="col s6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-content">
            <p class="card-title">{post.title}</p>
            <p>{post.body}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    {/each}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you haven't defined `posts` when Svelte renders you component. Ase you API call is async posts will be undefined by the time the `each` block runs.

All you have to do is define `posts` somewhere in your main script block:

```
let posts = [] // <- an empty array
```

Then after fetching it will re-render with your API posts.

Here is a [working demo in the REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/f85d597e4a0641fc958de4f1b2cda1b2?version=3.6.8) Note: I had to change your code slightly as the API I used had a different structure than your local one.

You can also look into [#await](https://svelte.dev/docs#await) which lets Svelte deal with async code. This isn't however suitable for all async problems. I use both approaches.

> TIP: You don't need to wrap your `onMount` function call. Svelte will only fetch your posts once.

Comment: @Gosmith - I updated the demo to include example of await syntax.

Comment: thanks  I  omitted the line "let posts = []" in my question but it was in my app code. Your answer did point out the problem.  I had to go 1 level deeper in the await with .post to get the array - as here -  "posts = (await res.json()).posts" and it works thanks!

Comment: @Gosmith ah yes, that would produce a similar error.